# Copiar rama a otra git

Tags: git, github, git-push

Resulta que he estado trabajando en la rama A mientras otra persona desde otro equipo realizo 2 commits a la misma rama e hizo push, ahora yo desde mi equipo no me deja hacer push con mis cambios sin antes hacer pull y traer esos 2 commits, como puedo deshacerlos o eliminarlos o pasar el contenido mio local a otra rama para finalmente hacer push e intregrar ?

Comment: porque no haces pull? y ya

Comment: Porque me trae los dos commits que no quiero porque no se necesitan y eran pruebas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el ancestro común entre tu versión local de la rama A y la suya sea el commit con sha `#asdfgh`

Si tu colega quiere preservar sus commits de prueba, puede moverlos a otra rama (lo mismo tú para mover los tuyos a una copia de ramaA si quieres seguir ese camino):

```
 git checkout ramaA
 git checkout -b RamaAModificada
```

Después puede pushear forzando a que el HEAD del remoto sea el ancestro común

```
git checkout ramaA
git reset --hard asdfgh
git push -f
```

Luego de eso, tú puedes traerte ese remoto que volvió a estar limpio y pushear sin inconvenientes:

```
git checkout ramaA
git fetch origin/ramaA
git push
```

Podría ser más corto que tú mismo hicieras desde ya

```
git push -f
```

Y con eso pisar lo que está en el remoto con lo que tienes en tu local, saliendo así los commits erróneos de la historia. Pero este camino deja abierto un flanco en donde tu colega no podrá trabajar con esa rama mientras siga teniendo los commits sucios.

Answer (score 1):

si lo que debes hacer es reintegran tus cambios en la misma rama A eliminando esos dos commits del repositorio remoto, primero partes de tu HEAD local en la rama A con tus commits actuales a una de respaldo:

```
git checkout -b ramaB
```

ahora la ramaA debe actualizar en el HEAD de origin, para eso debes devolverte al commit comun de donde parten los commits de la otra persona y los tuyos, si haces un git log, deberia de marcarse donde tienes tu origin actualmente ya que no has hecho pull, supongamos que es "abc123"

```
git checkout ramaA
git reset --hard abc123
```

ahora debes limpiar el repo remoto

```
git push origin ramaA --foce
```

integrar tus cambios

```
git merge ramaB
```

y por ultimo actualizar de nuevo el repo con tus cambios

```
git push origin ramaA
```